# Cities Skylines crashes everytime I load my save game

Tags: technical-issues, cities-skylines

This particular save game worked fine for me until last night, when it crashed and it crashes every time since then. This is what displays in the log file:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/nickg2794/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/nickg2794/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 255710
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198296880421 [API loaded no]
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/nickg2794/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Loading Mono
Mono location: /home/nickg2794/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Cities_Skylines/Cities_Data/Mono/x86_64
Native OpenGL graphics device hijacked
Loading Steamworks
Steam ID: 255710 [Message]
Timed out waiting for game mapping!
```

These are my system specs:

```
OS: Linux 4.4 LinuxMint 18 64bit
Language: English
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz (4 core(s))
System Memory: 7936
Gfx Device: GeForce GT 710/PCIe/SSE2
Gfx Version: OpenGL 4.5 [4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42]
Gfx Memory: 2048
Gfx Shader Model: 30
Game Version: 1.5.0-f4-steam-linux
```

If anyone has any idea how to get the game working again I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Does it crash when loading other savegames too?

Comment: Do you have any mods subscribed? Because the error is a rendering error, which could be caused by a mod. So I would unsub all mods and if that doesnt help, reinstall the game, if that doesnt work either, reinstall or update you graphics card drivers

Comment: The error is a red herring. See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Troubleshooting#Wrong_ELF_class. Steam defaults to loading 32-bit libraries for its game overlay even for 64-bit games and then fallbacks to the correct bitness. You should try to do a gdb/debugger backtrace instead to see what is actually going wrong (probably some sort of segfault/crash that does not appear in the log).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to disable/remove all the 3rd party mods that you have installed to your game and test it out by starting a new game. I had a similar problem some time back and following the same steps worked for me.

Do let me know the result.